# Найдите ошибку и как по-другому можно написать

Tags: python

Функция имеет три параметра: обязательный,необязателен, с переменным количеством аргументов. Составьте программу вычисления произведения чисел 3 на 7 и произведения чисел 4, 6, 7, 9, 10. Очень буду благодарен за Ваш помощь.

```py
def func(a, b=7, *c):
    x = a * b
    for i in c:
        x *= c
    return x


print(func(3))
print(func(4, 6, *[7, 9, 10]))
```

Comment: `return sum(x)` или сложить в цикле

Comment: `result=0;for el in x:result += el`

Comment: почему с переменным - у вас один аргумент всегда - список. А как посчитать сумму чисел в списке - это прям совсем азы

Comment: Ну либо имеется в виду *args

Comment: если можно, напишите пожалуйста код в упрощенном виде, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: я новичок пока учусь так что сильно не ругайте, возможно неправильно во все составил код и он не соответствует условию. Если можете помочь, то как можно по-другому составить код.

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста на код, очень срочно нужен

Comment: Вопрос как был непонятен, так и остался.

Answer (score 1):

Замените:

```
x *= c
```

на:

```
x *= i
```

Тогда код заработает правильно и выдаст правильный результат:

```
21
15120
```