# Посмотрите на код, как можно по-другому написать?

Tags: python

Функция имеет три параметра: обязательный, необязателен, с переменным количеством аргументов. Составьте программу вычисления произведения чисел 3 на 7 и произведения чисел 4, 6, 7, 9, 10.
``` `

```
def func(a, b=7, *c):
x = a * b
for i in c:
    x *= c
return x


print(func(3))
print(func(4, 6, *[7, 9, 10]))`
```

Comment: Не могу понять, как исправить чтобы он работал, Я новичок пока учусь, пожалуйста сильно не ругайте. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы сейчас на кортеж пытаетесь умножать, по которому идете: `x *= c`. А надо бы на числа, которые перебираете: `x *= i`

Comment: Понял, а во всём остальном код соответствует  с условии задачи?

Comment: Дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1378637

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать написать так:

```py
def func(a, *b):
    for n in b:
        a *= n

    return a


print(func(3))
print(func(4, 6, 7, 9, 10))
```

Выведет это:

```
3
15120
```